# UIButton inside UIView goes out of bounds

Tags: objective-c

I'm struggling with a problem that probably it's really stupid.
I've created an `UIView` and inside the `UIView` I've placed an `UIButton` and a `UISwitch`.
The `UIView` scales it's width based on the screen size keeping from left and right 45px, the `UISwitch` keeps it's frame size and the `UIButton` has its frame size changed based on the `UIView` frame size.

The problem is that the `UIButton's` text goes out of bounds for no reasons, this is the result I get:
[image]

The Blue background is the one of the `UIButton` and the Yellow background is the one of the `UIView`

I'm not able to align the text of the `UIButton` on top, this is what I've tried:

```
[_privacyButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)];
_privacyButton.titleLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentNone;
```

And also from the Storyboard I've set the vertical aligment top

Please someone help me, this UIButton is driving me crazy

Comment: How you exactly want layout?

Comment: @Jaimish I want the UIButton's title to respect it's frame, so the text will be aligned with the checkbox

Comment: Text is going beyond view shows it is not in the subview of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set constrains for the particular unbutton, i am unable to see you uiswitch, where you place it?.